# Ajax Serialize values different from 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this form:

```
<input type="text" class="Qty form-control input-sm" name="Qty"  value="0">
<input type="text" class="Qty form-control input-sm" name="Qty"  value="0">
<input type="text" class="Qty form-control input-sm" name="Qty"  value="0">
<input type="text" class="Qty form-control input-sm" name="Qty"  value="0">
```

The user will update the input boxes to random values.

On jquery I do this:

```
var TEST = $('.Qty').serialize();
```

And In PHP the output is (if only the first input is set to 5:

```
$TEST = $_POST['TEST'];
echo $TEST;

// OUTPUT: Qty=5&Qty=0&Qty=0&Qty=0
```

How can I get only values that are not 0?

```
// OUTPUT: Qty=5
```

I have tried:

```
var TEST = $('.Qty').not('[value="0"]').serialize();
```

But it's not working. Any Ideas?

Comment: i think your text box name should be like `name="Qty[]"`

Comment: @SureshKamrushi Why is that when he is using the class selector?

Comment: Use different ids having same ids is bad

Comment: ... and the text box id must be different

Comment: I have updated the code! I don't use id! And it's not working

Comment: What do you want to see? I am not sure if you have understand the basics of passing HTTP-POST parameters.

Comment: I want to get the values from the input boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want..... a custom filter function will root out the items with a value of zero.

[**DEMO on JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KV8SE/3/)

```
$('.Qty').filter(function() {
    return parseInt(this.value, 10) !== 0;
}).serialize()
```

Comment: @Dutchie432 If you write 0 into each `<input>`, you alert `Qty=0`. It seems that your [value!="0"] selector isn't working for me.

Comment: Hrm - that's strange. It appears it is functioning off of the original values. The items with the initial value set to `1` is always being returned. Sorry for not testing this better.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer to a working example using `filter` - sorry again for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var arr = new Array();
$('.Qty').each(function() {
 if ( $('.Qty').attr("value") != "0") {
 arr.push($('.Qty').attr("value")) 
}
});
arr.serialize();
```

Comment: On the ajax I use data: arr; ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I am afraid that you have totally misunderstood the concept of passing parameters/values via HTTP to a serverside script.

#### PHP (generate input-Elements)

```
$i = 0;
while (/*condition*/) {
  echo '<input type=text class=Qty name=parameter_'.$i.'>'
  $i++;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" class="Qty" name="parameter_1" value="value_1">
<input type="text" class="Qty" name="parameter_2" value="value_2">
<input type="text" class="Qty" name="parameter_3" value="value_3">
<input type="text" class="Qty" name="parameter_4" value="value_4">
<input type="text" class="Qty" name="parameter_5" value="value_5">
```

#### Javascript

```
sendThisToServer1 = $('.Qty').serialize();
$(".Qty").each(function() { sendThisToServer2[this.name] = $(this).val(); });
```

#### PHP (output results)

```
$first = $_POST['sendThisToServer1'];
$second = $_POST['sendThisToServer2'];

echo $first; // parameter_1=value_1&parameter_2=value_2&parameter_3=value_3&parameter_4=value_4
echo $second; // { parameter_1:values_1,parameter_2:value_2,parameter_3:value_3,parameter_4:value4 }
```

Comment: The problem is that the form is generated in a while cycle. The number of rows depend on the name of products. So how can i give diferent names to the inputs

Comment: `$i = 0; while(/*condition*/) { $input_name = 'parameter_'.$i; $i++; }` Here I'm using an index-variable (`$i`) which I'm incrementing each loop. Using this index-variable I can generate unique names for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that certain validation and check should be on the server-side because
client-side validations can be easily "ignored" by "no very nice" visitors.

**html:**
ID should be unique and appear only once in a page.
Changing the name to "Qty[]" will "create" an array on the server-side.

```
<input type="text" class="Qty form-control input-sm" name="Qty[]" id="Qty1" value="0">
<input type="text" class="Qty form-control input-sm" name="Qty[]" id="Qty2" value="0">
<input type="text" class="Qty form-control input-sm" name="Qty[]" id="Qty3" value="0">
```

**js:**

the same.

**php:**

```
$test = $_POST['TEST'];
foreach($test as $k => $v)
{
  if($v != 0)
  {
   // It's not 0, what do you want to do?
   //....
   //....
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the form is generated in a while cycle. The number of rows depend on the name of products

Comment: If so, you can use an ajax request for that validation.
If you prefer js-based solution, consider @user2211216 solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code as below in the HTML

```
<input type="text" class="Qty form-control input-sm" name="Qty[]"  value="0">
<input type="text" class="Qty form-control input-sm" name="Qty[]"  value="0">
<input type="text" class="Qty form-control input-sm" name="Qty[]"  value="0">
<input type="text" class="Qty form-control input-sm" name="Qty[]"  value="0">
```

when you click on the submit you can take the value by below PHP code.

```
$qty = $_POST['Qty'];
for($i=0;$i<count($qty);$i++)
{
    if($qty[$i]!='0')
    {
        echo 'Valid value';
    }   
    else
    {
        echo 'Invalid value';  
    }
}
```

Comment: But my form is made in a While cycle. The number of rows depend on the numbers of products. So How can I give different name to them?